# When do we use the suffix -ness

Tags: word-usage, suffixes

I'm a bit confused with this `-ness` suffix. I never know when to apply it.

For example this word got me confused : `powerlessness`. It looks like this suffix can be used in many cases. And I feel like there is a rule when to use this suffix, but I don't get it.

When are we supposed to use this suffix ? What does it express ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is used to convert an adjective to an abstract noun. For example,

> - Timely (Adj) -> Timeliness (Noun)
> - Bright (Adj) -> Brightness (Noun)

To convert adjectives and verbs to nouns, it is often attached with a suffix such as **-ness**, **-age**, **-ment**. etc.

Consider the following examples,

> - Fulfill (Verb) -> Fulfillment (Noun)
> - Cover (Verb) ->  Coverage (Noun)

To know more about the conversion of adjectives to abstract nouns, go to this [link](https://learningenglishgrammar.wordpress.com/suffixes/suffixes-and-how-they-form-abstract-nouns/).

Answer (score 1):

The suffix -ness is mainly added to adjectives and makes the adjective to a noun, meaning the quality or condition of what the adjective expresses.

"soft" has the noun softness, meaning the quality/condition of being soft.

[Oald, link](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/ness?q=-ness)

As to the origin of - ness, I would like to add to what etymonline says (related with German -nis as in Zeugnis, certificate/testimonial) I hold the view  that it is etymologically a left-right variant. If you read -ness backwards you get "sen", corresponding to German sein/das Sein, the being.

That some related words in one or two languages can be left-right variants is no official theory, it is rather a theory of mine. To back up this theory I have found about 250 incidents in a period of twenty years. The best known incident is Latin form-a and Greek morf-ae. Another example is English-German or German-German pot/der Pott and der Topf.